# Converting co-ordinates in VB2008

Tags: vb.net

I have co-ordinates in the form 57/20 and am looking to change this into -57,20 for use in a kml file for Google Earth, what code should I use to do this?

Comment: [please show what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I'm unsure of what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your needs are hard to understand.

If you just need to translate a coordinates such as `Point(x:=57, y:=20)` to `-57,20` (just the X coordinate as negative) then you can do this:

```
Dim OldCoordinates As New Point(x:=57, y:=20)

Dim NewCoordinates As New Point With
    {
        .X = OldCoordinates.X * -1I,
        .Y = OldCoordinates.Y
    }
```

Comment: I think it is a parsing and formatting thing.  He probably has a string "57/20" from somewhere and KML files use a format of `57,20`.  I dont know what the determinant is for making it negative (and he didnt say).

Comment: The only other thing is that the values for x and y can change, they are in the text box as x/y just now. Negative is because I am using west co-ordinates rather than east.

Comment: Apologies for it being unclear, the source of coordinates is displaying them as 57N/20W, in order for Google Earth to plot them, they need to be in the form -20,57,0. I hope to be able to do this just by replacing what's already in the box witht he new format.

Comment: So, your **real** question is "I have a string in a textbox which represents some coordinates in a format of `"57,20"`.  How do I parse that string and change the format to KML format which is `XX/YY`. I also need to be able to change the X (or maybe Y) to negative because ..."  The answer is *use String.Split with "/"c to get at the values then simply reformat them, maybe using String.Format or simply gluing them together. Since the negative seems conditional, you cant just use String.Replace on the `/`*